# Check if a function is doing AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin, where user can write their custom js function which is executed by plugin. They can share the codes to other and can import other's codes also. My concern is user can do ajax request via their function and can mess with database. So how do I check if a function is making ajax request and stop it from executing.

Solution i can think of are:-

- Block all ajax related keywords like AJAX, xmlhttp, GET, POST
- Having some global switch 
  `ajax = false;` 
   which line  will turn off all AJAX functions, and turn it on when required and turning off once done.

I have never faced security issues like this before, so don't have any idea.
What can be different ways user can mesh with database?

Comment: And if they do it with normal form submissions, links, img tags, etc?

Comment: Solution, you do not run JavaScript from other people in the same domain as your code. Look how stackoverflow does it with [snipplets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Since I am new to this field, so don't idea for different possible way to mesh with database.

Comment: doing `global:false` will stop all `ajax global functions declared anywhere in the application`

Comment: so you have exposed methods that allow for them to hit your database?

Comment: They can run js snippets, there no method exposed from which client can access db, but there snippet might have ajax requests which can do.

Comment: @GautamKumar http://blog.jsfiddle.net/doc-api-embedding or do the iframe yourself... You can not host the code in the same domain like I had 25 minutes ago.

Comment: If you haven't set up any handlers to catch those ajax requests, their requests wont do anything to your database.